# If the any part of the Contains in Cell A2 = “MAN” then add Man to cell B2

Tags: excel-2010

I am producing Upload CSV’s in Excel 2010  I am looking to make it easier and faster to upload products.
So I have a SKU e.g. GARM-GR18478TS-MAN-BLACK in Colum A2 
I would like to run a script to so that from the SKU the Following Info goes into the Different Cells.
If cell A2 Contains TS Then add T Shirt to cell B2
If Cell A2 Contains Man Then Add man to cell C2
And so on.
Appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly using Excel 2007, I think the formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(INDIRECT("J"&COLUMN()),$A2)),INDIRECT("K"&COLUMN()),"")
```

copied across (but no further than to ColumnI) and down to suit, though not a script (your question is not tagged for code) does achieve what your question asks (even if I have a suspicion this might not be quite what you really want!) provided there is a table of the kind shown, in ColumnsJ:K :

[image: SO17999656 example]

Comment: If you had "TS" in cell B1, "MAN" in cell C1, "WMN" in cell D1, etc, you could use this formula: `=IF(COUNTIF($A2,"*"&B$1&"*"),VLOOKUP(B$1,$J:$K,2,FALSE),"")`